# definite integral of piecewise function in R2

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> For $t\ge 0$ let
>
> $$ f(x,t) = 
> \begin{cases}
> x, & \text{if $0\le x \le \sqrt{t}$} \\
> -x+2\sqrt t,  & \text{if $\sqrt t \le x \le 2\sqrt t$} \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> For $t\lt 0$, let
>
> $$f(x,t) = -f(x,|t|)$$
>
> Define $F(t) = \int_{-1}^1 f(x,t) dx $.
>
> Show that $F(t) = t$ if $|t| \lt 0.25$.

Ummm... how can I integrate such a convoluted function? If $|t| \lt 0.25$ then x is indeed only non-zero between -1 and 1, so that makes sense. But I don't know where to start with integrating this. Can someone start me off right? Doesn't the function of x depend on what t is? But I'm not integrating over t at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For piecewise definitions, it always helps to visualize the transitions between domains. Let's consider a plot of $x$ (vertical) vs. $t$ (horizontal):

[image: a plot]

Because we are integrating over $x$, for each value of $t$ we consider a vertical path from $x=-1$ to $x=1$, and so can see that we should slice the integral at $0$, $\sqrt{|t|}$, and $2\sqrt{|t|}$. You are not integrating over $t$, but $t$ is a parameter which will affect, in this case, the region of integration and the function being integrated. So, a solution might start by writing
$$
F(x,t) = \left(\int_{-1}^0 + \int_0^{\sqrt |t|} + \int_{\sqrt |t|}^{2\sqrt{|t|}} + \int_{2\sqrt{|t|}}^1\right)f(x,t)\,dx~~,
$$
and considering the definition of $f$ on each subinterval. Can you take it from here?